# How to convert multiple records into single row using T-SQL PIVOT?

Tags: sql, pivot

I have a table that stores data for each type of record. I want to convert multiple rows into a single row using PIVOT function.

Input table:

[image]

Expected output:

[image]

I was able to PIVOT the table using CHAR_TYPE field but not getting the respective date for E_DATE and CO_DATE fields.

My code:

```
SELECT * FROM 
(
  SELECT ACCT, CHAR_TYPE, EFF_DATE, ADHOC_CHAR_VAL
  FROM ACCT
)  
PIVOT
(
  MIN(ADHOC_CHAR_VAL) FOR CHAR_TYPE IN ('C' AS C, 'M' AS M, 'E' AS E, 'CO' AS CO)
)
WHERE (C IS NOT NULL OR M IS NOT NULL OR E IS NOT NULL OR CO IS NOT NULL)
```

This is giving me output as:

[image]

**Please assist with the query to get data in expected output format.**

Comment: What does this have to do with T-SQL *and* Oracle SQL Developer? T-SQL is SQL Server's dialect and Oracle SQL Developer is an IDE like application for Oracle; they have little to do with each other.

Comment: The SQL language has a very strict rule that you MUST know about the number and data types of columns at query compile time, before looking at **any** data. If you know you need these specific fields from your table, this is possible, but if you want this to be dynamic you will not be able to do this in a single query. You'll need to use dynamic SQL to first run a query to find out your field names, and then use that info to build another query that gives you the final results.

Comment: Also, telling us you use sql developer is like telling us the car you drive is a Sony, because that's the brand name you see on the dashboard radio... fine for most people, but alarming to hear from your mechanic.

Comment: I am looking to PIVOT on specific fields only. Any assistance on the query will be much appreciated.